# Integration between Asp net Identity with API login

Tags: c#, api, model-view-controller, authorization

I have project MVC 5, I'm using Asp net Identity for login and registration and roles, I want add another authorization by API.

How I can add authorization by API to Asp net Identity to have two authorization  in project

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What do you mean two authorization ? Do you mean multiple policy , multiple roles , multiple claims ? If yes then I recommend you to read about authorization with policy and learn about policy requirement and policy handlers , then you could use this policy names with your action/controller

Comment: I mean multi of authorization, Use UseCookieAuthentication with OAuthOptions in the same project, I used UseCookieAuthentication  for user used web but my customer need api for mobile , So I want use OAuthOptions  to create token and send it to customer